# ASP.NET Entity Framework success message after registration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am really trying hard to make a popup message (success or error) when the user has finished registration. So in the `AccountController`, I made a `ViewBag` but since it redirects to `Login` right away, I've noticed that the message is not appearing or popping up.

How do I show the message?

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ....
        ViewBag.message= "Registered Successfully";

        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }
}
```

`_Layout` view:

```
<div class="container body-content">       
    @if (ViewBag.message!= null)
    {
        if (ViewBag.message.Equals("Registered Successfully"))
        {                
            <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                <strong>Success!</strong> @ViewBag.message
            </div>
        }
    }
    @RenderBody()              
</div>
```

Comment: `ViewBag` is for passing data from a controller to a view, but your doing a redirect (`ViewBag` is cleared). Pass the message to the method as a route value, or use `TempData`

Comment: Try a simple span element instead of bootstrap alert. If that works then bootstrap alert is your issue. And @stephen is correct. Use TemData if you redirect from one page to another

Comment: If you want bootstrap flash messages using TempData, you can try my solution https://www.nuget.org/packages/Santhos.Web.Mvc.BootstrapFlashMessages/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use TempData instead of the ViewBag

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
  TempData["Message"] = "Registered Successfully";
  return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}
```

In your view:

```
<div class="container body-content">       
@if (TempData["Message"] != null)
{
 ...
}
@RenderBody()              
</div>
```